# Data uploading from excel to database

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have one excel file which is updated daily, and I have to update the records in database(sql server 2005) daily.

What will be the query to fetch data from excel and update on database?

e.g the table structure like:

```
Empid   EmpName Emp.Des

001     Robert  Engineer

002 Philip  Trainer

003 John    Engineer
```

New excel is like:

```
004 Tom Engineer

005 Harry   Trainer

006 Samm    Engineer
```

So after the database update, the table will be look like:

```
001 Robert  Engineer

002 Philip  Trainer

003 John    Engineer

004 Tom Engineer

005 Harry   Trainer

006 Samm    Engineer
```

Comment: I would suggest making this into an SSIS package if it is to occur daily.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to do it using SQL you can do something like:

```
SELECT * INTO tableName FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Excel 8.0;Database=d:\xmlimport_test.xls', 'SELECT * FROM [Test$]')
```

[More examples](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321686)

But there are some requirements to meet:

1. You have 32bit SQL Server (there is no 64 bit driver for Excel)
2. You have to allow adhoc distributed queries

   ```
   sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
   GO
   RECONFIGURE;
   GO
   sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
   GO
   RECONFIGURE;
   GO
   ```

If you have 64bit SQL Server then you will get error: `MS Jet OLEDB 4.0 cannot be used for distributed queries because the provider is used to run in apartment mode.` There are some workarounds to this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/4887d91f-6ac7-40c0-9fc8-5cdd0634e603

But the best way would be to create SSIS package and schedule it as SQL Server job

Comment: Thanks for response But After executing I got an error message like Cannot process the object "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]". The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)" indicates that either the object has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object. Kindly suggest..

Comment: I assume that you want to get data from Sheet1 and excel file is **on the server** ?

Comment: Make sure of the following: 1. Excel file is on the server where you trying to import
2. Excel file does not have any spaces in it
3. Excel file has column names (first row)
4. Close the file if it is already being used by some other process

Comment: Thanks, It is creating new table but not appending the record next time ! Any suggestion ? Samar

Comment: You mean you have error? SELECT INTO creates new table, and next time it will throw error that `tableName` already exists. You can try using `INSERT INTO tableName (col1, col2, ...) SELECT (col1, col2, ...) FROM OPPENROWSET ...`

Comment: Thanks BartekR, I have done it successfully. Now I have another query like there are two different sheets in one excel file and I have to update the common data on a single table.

e.g there are two sheets having common column of empid(Excel and table name employee) and I have to update the empid which is present in two sheets.

Thanks
SamarS

Comment: Just run another query then (like `UPDATE`) using second worksheet. Something similar to `UPDATE tableName SET field1 = value1 FROM OPENROWSET(..., 'SELECT * FROM [Test2$]')`;

Comment: Sorry I have the query like
Table 1:
Empid EmpName Des
001 Samar eng
002 kalyan eng

Table 2:
Empid EmpName AccNo Emp.MobNo Emp.Address Empwork
001 Samar 1001 44545455646 ctc tttt
002 kalyan 1002 65464656654 bbs ppp
003 barak 1003 54654564564 polp ppp


Final Table:

Empid EmpName Des AccNo Emp.MobNo Emp.Address Empwork
001 Samar eng 1001 44545455646 ctc tttt
002 kalyan eng 1002 65464656654 bbs ppp

Comment: Please, don't go further in comments. Try to update your question or ask a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSIS to import Excel data to Database.  Here is [starting point](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79mi31caAag).

Answer (score 0):

**--Data Exporting from Excel to a NEW table in SQL Server**

```
SELECT * INTO tblImportedFromExcel 
FROM OPENROWSET
(
    'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
    'Excel 8.0;Database=c:\testing.xls;HDR=YES', 
    'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'
)
```

**--Data Exporting from EXCEL to an EXISTING table in SQL Server**

```
INSERT INTO tblImportedFromExcel 
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET
(
    'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
    'Excel 8.0;Database=c:\testing.xls;HDR=YES', 
    'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'
)
```

This would work for Excel 2003 file.