# From two Excel sheets to one DB table

Tags: sql-server

I have the query to solve out the following problem...
Excel Sheet1:

```
Empid   EmpName Des
001 Samar   eng
002 kalyan  eng
```

Excel Sheet2:

```
Empid   EmpName AccNo   Emp.MobNo   Emp.Address Empwork
001 Samar   1001    44545455646 ctc tttt
002 kalyan  1002    65464656654 bbs ppp
003 barak   1003    54654564564 polp    ppp
```

Final DB Table:

```
Empid   EmpName Des AccNo   Emp.MobNo   Emp.Address Empwork
001 Samar   eng 1001    44545455646 ctc tttt
002 kalyan  eng 1002    65464656654 bbs ppp
```

Comment: What exactly is your Question ...?\

Comment: Actually the above two tables are belongs to One excels's two sheets, and I have to update the DB table with common data on the basis of empid. Thanks

Comment: @DJ KRAZE It's question related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968470/data-uploading-from-excel-to-database

Comment: I saw that.. that's why I didn't respond with an answer.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

After you've imported your Excel sheets in a SQL Server instance, you can use the `INNER JOIN` syntax to select only rows that are present in both tables.

```
SELECT  s1.Empid
        , s1.EmpName
        , s1.Des
        , s2.AccNo
        , s2.[Emp.MobNo]
        , s2.[Emp.Address]
        , s2.[Empwork]
FROM    sheet1 s1
        INNER JOIN sheet2 s2 ON s2.Empid = s1.Empid
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a select from Sheet1 and Sheet2 that gives final table, it would be like this:

```
INSERT INTO finalDBtable
Select s1.*, s2.AccNo, s2.[Emp.MobNo] , s2.[Emp.Address], s2.Empwork
from Sheet1 s1
inner join Sheet2 s2 on s1.Empid = s2.Empid
```

---

So, first put Sheet1 and Sheet2 in database tables and then make the select previous select to insert in the final table.